# Render partial in layout file with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, renderpartial

The navigation for my site is obviously stored in the application layout file. Part of that navigation is driven by the database. How to I render a partial in the layout and pass in the collection of objects for it to render?

EDIT:
I think my question revolves more around how to get data into the partial, is that done form the application controller or do I have to add the data in each action on each controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wish to pass one object in then you can use the `object` key on `render`. The passed object will be accessible as an local variable of the same name as the partial. SO if the partial is called `navigation` the local variable will be `navigation`.

```
<%= render :partial => 'foo/navigation', :object => @my_collection
```

In the partial:

```
<% for obj in navigation %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If you wish to pass multiple objects then you can use the `locals` key. The names of the local variables in your layout are then the keys of the passed hash.

```
<%= render :partial => 'foo/navigation', :locals => { :foo => 'Hello', :bar => 'World' }
```

In the partial:

```
<%= foo %>
<%= bar %>
```

Comment: So in your first example foo would be the name of an action that gets the data @my_collection?

Comment: In the first example foo is the views subdirectory that the partial is in.

Comment: Full documentation is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

Comment: Ok, guess my question really is then how do I get data into the partial, can I do that from the application controller?

Comment: Define `@my_collection` in your controller or application_controller.

Comment: or if something like user navigation store the user id in a session and then query the db using the session user id